# Create a directory based on the start of a file name

Tags: batch-file

I wish to migrate a massive collection of files (eBooks), based on text at the start (author's name)
I've tried coding a batch file, but I'm missing something fundamental.

Almost all of the files are

```
"Authors name - Book title.extention"
"Authors name - [Book series] - Book title.extention"
```

I wish to pass each file through a script (preferably a Batch file) that identifies the Author's name part (basically looks for the first " - ", and then creates a directory based on the starting trimmed string.

I've crafted a FOR & IF command based on research, but part of it doesn't work

```
SET str=%1%

FOR /L %%a in (1,1,50) do (

    if "!str:~%%a,3!"==" - " (
        set DName=!str:~0,%%a-1!
        MD DName
        MOVE %1 DName
        EXIT
    )
)
```

I don't fully understand the string truncation command "STRING:~STARTING POSITIONWITHINSTRING,STRINGLENGTH". I keep finding examples of people using it like it just works, but I'm failing at finding documentation explaining how it's meant to operate.

Can what I'm asking be done as a BATCH file? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's `%variable:~start_index,substring_length%`. Indices are 0-based.

Comment: When you say " I'm failing at finding documentation explaining how it's meant to operate.", I am certain that when you open a Command Prompt window, type `set /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, there is information about environment variable expansion and substitution.

Answer (score 4):

Use a little trick to get rid of the delimiter string and title (Attention: it does not work with recommended syntax `set "var=value"`, so use extreme care to not add any spaces with the `set folder...` command)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=%~1"
SET "file=Authors name - Book title.extention"
set folder=%file: - =&REM %
ECHO md "%folder%" 2>nul
ECHO move "%file%" "%folder%\"
```

Remove the `SET` line (just for demonstration) and (after verifying it's working as intended), both `ECHO` commands.

Works even with author names containing `-`, like `Karl-Heinz Writer` because this splits by a string `<space><dash><space>`, which `for` isn't able to do.

Answer (score 1):

The task can be done with a batch file with following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "* - *" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do for /F "eol=| delims=-" %%J in ("%%I") do (
    if not exist "%%~nxJ" md "%%~nxJ"
    if exist "%%~nxJ" move "%%I" "%%~nxJ\"
)
endlocal
```

The command **DIR** searches

- in the current directory
- just for files because of option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- of which file names is matched by the wildcard pattern `* - *`
- and outputs the found file names in bare format because of option `/B` which means just with file name and extension without path.

It is possible that no file name is found matching the criteria which would result in an error message written to handle **STDERR**. This possible error message is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `cmd.exe /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.

The output of **DIR** in background command process is captured by **FOR** and processed line by line.

**FOR** on using option `/F` skips empty lines which do not occur here at all. The default behavior on processing a captured line by **FOR** is splitting the line up into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and assigned just the first space/tab separated string to the specified loop variable `I`. This line splitting behavior is not wanted for the file names output by **DIR** as the file names definitely contain spaces and the entire file name is needed for further processing the files. For that reason the option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters to turn off line splitting behavior and so get the file name with extension assigned to the loop variable `I`.

**FOR** on using option `/F` would also look on first character of first substring and would ignore the line for further processing if it starts with a semicolon which is the default end of line character. It is very unlikely that an author name starts with `;`, but there is nevertheless used the option `eol=|` to redefine the end of line character with a vertical bar which no file name can contain ever.

The second `for /F` is used to split up the file name string using `-` as string delimiter and get just the first substring assigned to the specified loop variable `J`. That works for your file names as long as the author names do not contain `-` inside. So `J` is defined on each file name with `Authors name`  with the space left to the hyphen as trailing space.

The Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) explains how Windows handles file/folder names with trailing spaces/dots by removing them. For that reason `%%~nxJ` is used to reference the string up to first `-` with trailing space(s) and dot(s) removed independent on subdirectory according to author's name already existing or not.

The first **IF** condition is used to check if the subdirectory according to author's name does not exist in which case the subdirectory is created using the command **MD** to make the directory.

The second **IF** condition is used to verify if the subdirectory according to author's name exists now and if that is the case as expected, the file is moved using command **MOVE** into the subdirectory.

A variant of above is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "* - *" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do for /F "eol=| tokens=1* delims=-" %%J in ("%%I") do (
    if not exist "%%~nxJ" md "%%~nxJ"
    if exist "%%~nxJ" for /F "eol=| tokens=*" %%L in ("%%K") do move "%%I" "%%~nxJ\%%L"
)
endlocal
```

The difference is that every file is moved into the subdirectory with a new name with everything up to first hyphen and all spaces after the first hyphen removed from the file name to have the files in the subdirectories without author's name in file name.

The main advantage of using command line without the usage of environment variables and delayed variable expansion is that this code works also for file names containing one or more exclamation marks.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. And thank you for explaining how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way you can split up a string using multiple characters for the delimiter. This uses some very unique aspects of how variable values are expanded before execution of the line of code.

```
SET "var=Authors name - Book title.extention"
set "Author=%var: - =" & set "Book=%"

Echo Author=%Author%
echo Book=%Book%
```

Which would give this for output.

```
Author=Authors name
Book=Book title.extention
```